# Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json in mac M1 docker build

Tags: docker, macos, .net-core, dockerfile, nuget

I am trying to create a docker image for my dotnetcore application. but i am getting

> Unable to load the service index for source
> https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
> error on step `RUN dotnet restore.`

Things i have tried so far.

- tried nuget restore from visual studio -its working
- tried accessing https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json in browser - able to browse
- tried editing docker json DNS value to "8.8.8.8"
- verified PING google.com from docker container and ping is successful

So i am not sure anything related to my M1 processor or any proxy issue. I have gone through lot of online links but all are related to windows. Any help on this is appreciated. Below is my ~/nuget/Nuget/Nuget.config file and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore  "myapplication.Web/myapplication.Web.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/myapplication.Web"
RUN dotnet build "myapplication.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
WORKDIR "/src/myapplication.Web"
RUN dotnet publish "myapplication.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapplication.Web.dll"]
```